# Software que precisa licença para uso comercial

Tags: licença, software

Na empresa XYZ foi baixado o software InfoRapid Search & Replace para utilizar no departamento de TI para quando, por exemplo, se faz necessário alterar uma mesma linha de código em vários fontes do sistema interno que é dado manutenção.

Sabe-se que se esse software for usado para uso comercial, é necessário licenciá-lo.

A empresa em questão, que não é uma softwarehouse e sim uma indústria (ou seja, não vende software), precisa também pagar a licença mesmo que seja apenas para uso interno?

Comment: Não entendi por que negativaram a pergunta.

Comment: Também não sei por que negativaram, mas isso me parece pergunta de trabalho de faculdade de Gestão de TI. Acertei? :D É provável que tenha que licenciar sim, mas pra ter certeza você tem que ler a licença e se ainda tiver dúvidas, consultar um advogado (ou, se for questão de faculdade, basta encontrar a resposta "certa" no livro hehehe).

Comment: Não é trabalho de faculdade. É um caso real, de uma empresa real, mas obviamente que não vou passar todos os detalhes na pergunta. Fui direto ao ponto.

Comment: Ok, mas fica valendo o que eu disse: tem que estudar a licença, não há outra forma de saber. Se você tiver sorte, passa por aqui alguém que já estudou essa licença antes (difícil heim).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A grande maioria dos softwares a licença é relacionada ao uso do produto em questão, independente da área de atuação de quem compra o produto e no [site do produto](http://www.inforapid.de/html/searchreplace.htm) não existe nenhum tipo de concessão de uso relacionado com área de atuação. A única condição para uso gratuito é para fins não comerciais.

> InfoRapid Search & Replace is freeware and may be copied, distributed and used for private purposes without any limitations. Installing and using the freeware version on a commercially used computer is absolutely prohibited. **In order to use the program commercially, you need one license
>   (25 Euro) for every user**. If you want to license InfoRapid Search & Replace for more than 10 users, then you can also buy a much cheaper site license. Please ask me for details.

Você pode obter mais informações no site do desenvolvedor ou entrar em [contato com eles](http://www.inforapid.de/html/srcontact.htm) para esclarecer qualquer outra dúvida.

No brasil as condições para licenciar e as penalidades cabíveis para quem não o faz são descritas na [lei Nº 9.609, de 19 De Fevereiro de 1998](http://www.planalto.gov.br/CCivil_03/LEIS/L9609.htm). Recomendo legalizar o software em questão econsultar um advogado para orientar como agir com essa situação.

Comment: Grato pela resposta. A empresa decidiu que o software deve ser desinstalado pra evitar futuras complicações.

Answer (score 3):

Em qualquer lugar, principalmente empresa com cnpj, devidamente cadastrada, só deve usar de produto licenciado, exceto nos caso em que a desenvolvedora do software permite uso com versao limitada, para intuito de aprendizagem ou nao comerciais.

Eu trabalho em industria. Pensei em "crackear" um software de CAD (desenho auxiliado por computador). A gestão de TI me informou que, mesmo se eu conseguisse instalar, com ou sem permissao da empresa, seriamos rastreados, a receita ou a policia fedral seriam acionados, e a empresa no minimo seria multada.

Já trabalhei em empresa, de pequeno porte, que pirateava os softwares para que os funcionarios trabalhassem. Um risco pois eventualmente o ministerio do trabalho faz auditoria em empresas de engenharia e eles consultam os licenciamentos.

Comment: Lembro que a Embraer levou uma multa grande por causa de software pirata que virou notícia. Se a licença do software não permite a utilização gratuita para o uso não comercial, é melhor evitar.

Comment: Grato pela resposta. A empresa decidiu que o software deve ser desinstalado pra evitar futuras complicações.